# If i use reflections to get the classes extending a common class will the list contain all the recursively inherited classes too?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflections

Suppose I have

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}
class C extends A{}
class D extends C{}
class E extends B{}
```

and I have the following code

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections();    
Set<Class<? extends A>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(A.class);
```

will the set `classes` contain classes `D` and `E`???

Comment: Try it and let us know!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
import java.util.Set;

import org.reflections.Reflections;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections();
        Set<Class<? extends A>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(A.class);
        System.out.println(classes);
    }
}

class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends A {
}

class D extends C {
}

class E extends B {
}
```

Output: `[class C, class D, class B, class E]`